# Excel VBA: Turn Cells into hyper-links and ignore empty values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA script:

```
Sub ConvertToHyperlinks()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Application.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, "http://" & Rng.Value
Next
End Sub
```

It takes the selected cells and convert them into hyper-links which can be clicked on.
for example if the cell has a value of *"example.com"* it will be turned to "http://example.com"

It works fine, the only thing is that if the cell is empty it will still turn it into a hyper-link  with a value of *"http://"*

How can i make it ignore cells which have empty values and not add the *"http://"* to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (you only need 1 line for your `WorkRng` as well)

```
Sub ConvertToHyperlinks()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, Selection.Address, Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    If Len(Rng.Value) > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Rng, "http://" & Rng.Value
Next
End Sub
```